# pass collection during redirect to route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, routes

I have a form in a view where a user can add an item to the DB.
After successful insert in the DB I want to redirect to a view that has latest entries from other users but I want to send along the item that the user just added.
I mean to save a DB query in that view controller where then I should only retrieve for example the latest 10 entries from other users less the one that the auth user just added.
Is it possible?

Comment: If it's one list, why just not get last 11 records? If it's a list and you want to show added record separately, just get it and pass to that view.

Comment: what if in the meantime some other 11 users are adding items and you don't see your posting in the resulting view because now it's the 12th?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to display recently added record separately. In this case, you can pass data to the view after inserting it to DB. Something like:

```
$otherUsersLastItems = Model::latest()->take(10)->get();
$lastItem = Model::create($request->all());
return view('some.view', compact('otherUsersLastItems', 'lastItem'));
```

Comment: what does  Model::create($request->all());  does ?

Comment: `create()` creates a record using mass assignment. `$request()->all()` is an array with request data (usually it's data from submitted form). https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: ok ok I get it. I am creating the model differently as I need to pass some data that is not in the request.

Comment: Doesn't matter, `create()` will return an object with correct data as you would get it from DB.